# Comparing repeated measures ordinal data over time between two groups

Tags: repeated-measures, ordinal-data

I have ordinal data from two groups over time. I want to know the if the data are different between the two groups at each time point.  I know it should be a non-parametric test but am not sure how to get the multiple comparisons that I want. Currently using Graphpad prism for analysis although I can also use R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible in GraphPad Prism.

There are some software packages in R that are designed to handle this type of modeling where you want to use a random effect to account for longitudinal sampling and your response is ordinal.

Check out the [mixor R package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mixor). The [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixor/vignettes/mixor.pdf) includes an example of longitudinal data.